# Undefined array index on for loop from conditionals

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

So, I have an instance where I'm filtering some arrays and I've ended up with undefined in my array.  I can't have this since it affects the function I pass this array to.  I want the array to build only what has data.  Refer to my example code and I'm sure you'll see what I mean:

```
var foo = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'one', 'one'];
var bar = [];

for (var i=0, l = foo.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(foo[i].includes('one') !== false){
        bar[i]=foo[i];
    }
}
console.log(bar);
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o3b1m2u0/

I tried using another counter and offsetting it but I can't seem to get it right.  Ideas?

Comment: Yes, you will need a second counter (if you don't want to simply use `push`). Please show us your attempt at doing so, otherwise we cannot tell you what went wrong and how to improve it.

Comment: Btw, is it intentional that something like `'fourtyone'` or `'onehundred'` would get picked as well?

Comment: `var bar = foo.filter(e => e.includes('one'))` would also accomplish this task.

Comment: Just "push" the value. I ran into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you're adding things to the array in a position that doesn't exist. All items that you haven't defined in your loop will be set as undefined. Use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead.

```js
var foo = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'one', 'one'];
var bar = [];

for (var i=0, l = foo.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(foo[i].includes('one') !== false){
        bar.push(foo[i]);
    }
}
console.log(bar);

//you could also use .filter

var bar2 = foo.filter(f => f.includes('one'))
console.log('bar2', bar2)

//a third option is to use .map if you need something else other than undefined as a placeholder

var bar3 = foo.map((f,i) => f.includes('one') ? f : i)
console.log('bar3', bar3)
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer!  I'm not sure in which cases it would be better to use one over the other but I will try to figure it out with the documentation.  It looks like filter would be the best use since I'm attempting to filter data.

Answer (score -1):

the index i is index of array foo,if you write in your way,the array bar is becoming a Sparse array

Comment: The OP knows that this is happening. He's asking how to avoid it.